# jOOQ Kotlin Coroutines - Select all and exists queries

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, jooq

I would like to use jOOQ with Kotlin Coroutines but I'm unable to find documentation or example code to know how to use it correctly.

I would like to select all rows that match my query and map them into my POJO.

I've tried a variety of combinations. `fetchAsync` sounds correct but the return type is incorrect after mapping

**Incorrect return type of `(Mutable)List<Model!>`**

```
open suspend fun findAll(): Flow<Model> {
    return ctx.select()
        .from(table)
        .fetchAsync()
        .await()
        .into(modelClass)  // Into is blocking
}
```

If I wanted this to be blocking I could use:

```
return ctx.select()
    .from(table)
    .fetchInto(modelClass)
```

But there is no `fetchAsyncInto` method.

Also, if I wanted to do an exists query I can see how it's done by blocking, but not asynchonously.

E.g.

```
ctx.fetchExists(dslContext.selectFrom(table).where(YOUR_TABLE.ID.eq(id))
```

How can I perform a select all and exists query using jOOQ with Kotlin Coroutines?

**Update**
I can get this working with a Flux.

```
Flux.from(ctx.select().from(table))
.map { record -> record.into(modelClass) }
.asFlow()
```

**Exists query update**

This works successfully but isn't directly running an exists query.

```
val result =  ctx.selectFrom(table)
    .where(USER_MODEL.EMAIL.eq(email))
    .awaitFirstOrNull()

    return result != null
```

I've tried writing the query like so but it throws an `Cannot execute query. No JDBC Connection configured` exception:

```
select(
    exists(
        ctx.selectFrom(table)
           .where(USER_MODEL.EMAIL.eq(email))
    )
).awaitFirst().into(Boolean::class.java)
```

Comment: The `Result.into()` method isn't blocking, but `fetchAsync` is (it's implemented on top of JDBC and blocks on that, but possibly on a different thread). The error you're running into is that there's no automatic cast / conversion / whatever, between `List` and `Flow`. You have to do that either explicitly, or use jOOQ's reactive APIs (not async APIs!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from `jOOQ` 3.17, the `jooq-kotlin-coroutines` extension module allows for bridging between the reactive streams API and the coroutine APIs.

And you have to add next one dependency to the project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-kotlin-coroutines</artifactId>
  <version>version</version>
</dependency>
```

To have more details check [Kotlin coroutine support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/kotlin-sql-building/kotlin-coroutines/)

**Update**

Your query should look as next one
*pseudocode*

```
Flux.from(
     ctx.select()
     .from(table)
     .fetchInto(modelClass)
  ) 
  .asFlow()
```

Comment: I'm using `jooq-kotlin` and `jooq-kotlin-coroutines`.  implementation("org.jooq:jooq-kotlin-coroutines:3.18.7")

Comment: I did an update could you try, I provided it as pseudocode the example, could you try ?

Comment: I can get it working with similar but slightly different code. (It maps afterwards). 
How would I go about doing this without Flux?

Comment: I've updated the question with working code.

Comment: Why you don’t like it ?

Comment: I didn't see why I needed to use a Flow. I've managed it thank you! I've accidentally updated your answer but it's probably best it's there.

Comment: Actually I take that back. It only works with Flow.

Answer (score 1):

The question mixes multiple concerns:

#### What's really blocking in your example

The [`Result.into()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Result.html#into(java.lang.Class)) method isn't blocking, but `fetchAsync()` could be considered blocking, given that it is implemented only for JDBC clients for now, and will thus block on some thread.

#### The actual error you ran into

The error you're running into is that there's no automatic cast / conversion / whatever, between List and Flow. You have to do that either explicitly, or use jOOQ's reactive APIs (not async APIs!).

[The kotlin coroutine support is documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/kotlin-sql-building/kotlin-coroutines/). It will work the same way for `Flow`, it's just a matter of converting jOOQ's provided `Publisher<R>` type to a `Flow<R>` type.

#### Exists queries

The `DSLContext.fetchExists(query)` method is just convenience for `select(exists(query)).fetchOneInto(Boolean::class.java)`, more or less. You can write that yourself, explicitly.

Most jOOQ users use the blocking JDBC APIs. While it would be possible to replicate each and every one of these convenience methods also for jOOQ/R2DBC users, it's also very simple to write such convenience libraries on your end, knowing that they're just convenience for an actual jOOQ query.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I've updated my question. I can successfully get the query working by doing a select and checking if I get a result. I'm having an error occur if I try writing it in a similar fashion to how you mentioned. 
What am I likely doing wrong?

Comment: @Michael: It would be better to ask new questions rather than editing questions with new updates, which can be very confusing for future readers. Your original question already mixed 3 concerns, now you've added one more thing, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I'll be happy to answer your follow-up question.

Comment: Apologies yes I'll create a separate question.